# Why is a static method giving me an error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.6

Call to a possibly undefined method test through a reference with static type Class.

here is my class

```
package com.singleton.sample{
    public class SampleSingleton{

        public static function test( ):void{
            trace('hello world')
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" applicationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton;
            public function init():void{

                SampleSingleton.test() // error on this line
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Please ignore the singleton references in the naming as I stripped down my class to this and it still doesn't work.

[EDIT]

```
import com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton;
public function init():void{
  SampleSingleton.test(); // this gives me the error
  com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton.test(); // this works
}
```

Comment: Can you add non-static methods to the SampleSingleton class and create an instance and call those methods in the init method? The code looks fine to me, might be something wrong with the project/class path etc.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. The only thing I can think of, is that `SampleSingleton` is not in the correct package physically.

Comment: @RIAstar I thought so to but when I typed the import statement the IDE autogenerated com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton. So I don't know. This is a new project so something isn't set right

Comment: @Baris Usakli good point so I created an instance and tried to access another non-static function i just made and it can't find that either. Oh and let me add that the class is in a folder outside of the project. I added the folder to the project when I created the project.

Comment: The auto-generated package is the one declared in the class' `package` statement, not the physical path. Nevertheless, if this were the issue, you should get an error message like `A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure 'com.singleton.sample', as the definition's package`.

Comment: @RIAstar yeah I don't get it I just deleted the project folder and recreated it and I still get the same error. The auto gen stuff is telling me that the linkage is good. I can instantiate the class just can not access the methods.

Comment: @BarisUsakli If I target the class directly I can access the methods otherwise its a no go var WTF:com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton = new com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton()

Comment: Is there another SampleSingleton in the project? Maybe some duplicate class without the test method.

Comment: @BarisUsakli no I just recreated the project again but this time I did not add the linked path. I then moved just the com.singleton.sample files into my src folder. I can still import it but I can not access the methods still. The src structure is like this src/com/singleton/sample

Comment: Can you access the static method by using the full name of the class?
com.singleton.sample.SampleSingleton.test(); ??

Comment: @BarisUsakli yes updated my question to show what I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Application file is named SampleSingleton i bet so you have a name collision. Rename the application.

Comment: good call I should have tried it myself. I knew it was a stupid mistake. Renaming the mxml worked.